# I installed a Python program but can't find all it's source code

Tags: python, linux, bash

This is a question about Python program packaging and distribution.  I installed *SomeProgram* from the Internet that requires Python.  It works exactly like it's supposed to.  There is only one single file that I can find associated with it located in \usr\bin\  It does not have a ".py" file extension, but I can open in it Python's IDLE text editor.  There are just a few lines and less than 100-bytes long.

Also, it runs within BASH and accepts arguments and lots of options including some like -h for help or --verbose for alternate output. I wouldn't know it's a python program except that my understanding is that it's written in python.

I'm understanding that the code here is instructing it to import itself.  The file is the SAME NAME [wrong see update] as the file it's asking to import, and there is no .py extension for the actual filename.  Here is the code, [I've swapped out the name with SomeProgram because its a commercial enterprise name I don't want to print online]:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import SomeProgram

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SomeProgram.main()
```

I want to understand where the main() source code is and learn from it.  The program is fairly complex but I can't find it.

**UPDATE:**
Problem solved. While finding the source code using the posted help below, I discovered that the file-name and and imported package-name are actually different.  There is a hyphen within the python filename in my `/usr/bin/` location, while the import-name has an underscore.  It turns out that the source code is here:  `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SomeProgram`

Comment: Just print `SomeProgram.__file__`......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program loads its own module which is probably installed in Python's `site-packages` directory.

Open an Python interactive Python session and use these commands to find out where that is:

```
import site
site.getsitepackages()
```

Example:

```
> python 
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 28 2016, 20:51:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final 262564)] on freebsd11
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/site-python']
```